Get files in folder Action no longer working with variables
We've been developing and trialing a Power Automate automation with our Finance team which has been progressing well until recently when the "Get files in folder" activity started complaining with the following error:   "Parameter 'Folder': Argument 'Folder' must be 'Folder'.
If I edit the activity and select a specific folder in the system it works as expected, but defeats the purpose of the automation. We need to be able to iterate over a list of location in an excel file and set the folder locations via variables.
anyone experiencing this problem or have an idea on how to get around it?



You need to show us something, simple as that.  Show us the flow and the parameters into the relevant operations, etc.

I've added a couple of screenshots for reference. Also, we're using powerfx in case that's relevant.

That’s PA desktop

Seems you have entered the variable as a string hence the error. Try selecting it with the blue {x} button.
